# How do I compare a file in git with another revision of another file?

Tags: git, diff

I have a file called file.txt.  I copy it, call it fileOld.txt and make some small changes.  I then make bigger changes to file.txt.  I have not committed anything.

How can I see what changes I made in fileOld.txt, ie. how can I compare fileOld.txt with the latest committed version of file.txt?

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
diff -u <(git show origin/HEAD:file.txt) fileOld.txt
```

which is fine, but I wondered if git supported this directly somehow?

Comment: use any diff viewer (kdiff3, for eg.): `kdiff fileOld.txt file.txt`. Since you have not committed anything, no need for `git show...`

Comment: I want to compare fileOld.txt with the previous version of file.txt, before I made any changes to file.txt, whereas comparing file.txt and fileOld.txt includes changes I've made to file.txt.

Comment: You can have 3 way diff in kdiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diffs file1.txt from the previous commit to your current file2.txt.

```
git diff HEAD^:file1.txt file2.txt
```

You can ofcourse replace HEAD^ with the commit SHA1.

Comment: Actually, since I've not committed yet, `git diff HEAD:file1.txt file2.txt` also works.

Comment: Didn't know that , but it makes sense, since file1 is taken from the last commit, and file2 is the one on the file system since it's not specified with a revision.